# owl-carousel does not scroll smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

The carousel can be viewed [here](http://timothymaryon.com/about.html) under 'clients worked with'.

You'll notice the carousel starts reasonably smoothly then after a second or so starts to stagger. When it gets to what I can only assume is the end of it's play time, it then looks like it almost resets the position.

Here's the JS I'm using:

```html
<script src="javascripts/custom/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/custom/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 10,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 1000,
    smartSpeed: 2500,
    fluidSpeed: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true
  });

  $('.play').on('click', function() {
    owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000])
  })

  $('.stop').on('click', function() {
    owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
  })
</script>
```

Comment: could you do a fiddle out of that? it would be much easier to help you :)

Comment: I don't believe that Owl Carousel is able to smoothly scroll. The reason for the pause is because there's a small delay between the animation of each slide's movement. It sounds more like you want marquee behaviour, so I'd suggest using a library which has that functionality instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't realise it didn't contain that functionality! I have probably got it the best I can for now if I continue using the owl-carousel then. Hmm, thanks for the heads up!